# Facebook Invite not showing push notification to recipient

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, push-notification

I am testing sending invites form my game to another Facebook account.  That user **does** get the notification in Facebook globe section if I open Facebook and look for it, but it does not send them a push notification.  I have tested with some other games like Happy Street iOS for example and I do get a push notification from Facebook when I send an invite from that game.  So I am wondering if there is anything I have configured wrong?

Other details.  Using Facebook 6.0 SDK for Unity3D on iOS.

Comment: facing the same issue.Any luck

Comment: This seems to just be some kind of hidden algorithm that Facebook uses to determine when to send push notifications. I have noticed some of my other games don't always send them either. I would love some clarification on this though.

Comment: same issue I am facing, I have created two test accounts and tried with that but still no luck.

Comment: I have the same problem. Does anybody find answer?